# Getting attribute from Terrafrom cdk deployed lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform CDK to deploy a lambda function and am trying to set a trigger to it using s3 notifications. I'm sorta new to CDK, so I'm not sure where things might be going wrong here.

Reading this [example](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/blob/main/examples/python/aws/main.py) and based also on what's done using regular CDK, I thought that to access the function arn (so to add it to bucket notification setting), it'd be `my_function.arn`, but it renders the following string
`{TfToken[TOKEN.XXX]}`.

It seems to me that I'd be able to fetch the arn somewhere with this value, but I couldn't find out where.

I thought of breaking it up into two stacks, but I needed both lambda and its notification trigger to be deployed together.

The code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack, TerraformOutput
from imports.aws import AwsProvider
from imports.aws.lambdafunction import LambdaFunction
from imports.aws.s3 import S3BucketNotification, S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction
import os

class My_Stack(TerraformStack):
  def __init__(self, scope: Construct, ns: str):
    super().__init__(scope, ns)

    AwsProvider(self, 'Aws', region='my-region')

    my_lambda_function = LambdaFunction(
      self, id='id',
      function_name='cdk-deployment-test',
      role='my-role',
      memory_size=128,
      runtime='python3.8',
      timeout=900,
      handler="lambda_handler",
      filename=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'deployment_package/package.zip')
    )

    function_to_be_triggered = S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction(
      lambda_function_arn= my_lambda_function.arn,
      events = ["s3:ObjectCreate:*"],
      filter_prefix = "path"
    )

    payment_recognition_input = S3BucketNotification(
      self, id='s3-bucket-notification',
      bucket = 'my-bucket',
      lambda_function=[function_to_be_triggered]
    )

app = App()
My_Stack(app, "cdktf-poc")

app.synth()
```

Comment: why are you mixing and matching deployment services? Use either CDK or terraform, but imo using both overcomplicates things.

Comment: I'm not mixing'em. I'm using only Terraform cdk for the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to reference the terraform resource's ARN property, the `{TfToken[TOKEN.XXX]}` tokens resolve to Terraform language syntax in the synth output. Check out the CDK For Terraform documentation here that discusses tokens:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/blob/main/docs/working-with-cdk-for-terraform/tokens.md#tokens

For example, this CDKTF code:

```js
const vpc = new Vpc(this, "my-vpc", {
  name: vpcName,
});

new Eks(this, "EksModule", {
  clusterName: "my-kubernetes-cluster",
  vpcId: vpc.vpcIdOutput,
});
```

ultimately generates (using token) this terraform:

```json
{
  "module": {
    "helloterraEksModule5DDB67AE": {
      "cluster_name": "my-kubernetes-cluster",
      "vpc_id": "${module.helloterraMyVpc62D94C17.vpc_id}"
    }
  }
}
```

So that that reference and dependency link still exist at Terraform plan/apply time.

For your specific use case, have tried out the following, using the pre-built aws provider and `S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction` for structuring the lambda function configuration:

```py
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_aws.s3 import S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction, S3BucketNotification
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_aws.lambda_function import LambdaFunction

my_lambda_function = LambdaFunction(
    self, id='id',
    function_name='cdk-deployment-test',
    role='my-role',
    memory_size=128,
    runtime='python3.8',
    timeout=900,
    handler="lambda_handler",
    filename=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'deployment_package/package.zip')
)

S3BucketNotification(
    self,
    id="s3-bucket-notification",
    bucket="my-bucket",
    lambda_function=[
        S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction(
            lambda_function_arn=my_lambda_function.arn,
            events=["s3:ObjectCreate"],
            filter_prefix="path"
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: thanks for the documentation. If I got it right, this was supposed to work right ?
I'm getting the error ```Error: error putting S3 Bucket Notification Configuration: InvalidArgument: The ARN is not well formed```. I used cdktf plan and reading the .json file it seems that I'm missing some configuration here, even though I'm following this example
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification#bucket from the terraform.

The specs seems to follow the same pattern as seen in Lambda deployment

Comment: Yea your code should work - have tested it out myself with 2 small tweaks - I'm using the pre-built aws provider, and also the `S3BucketNotificationLambdaFunction` - will update my answer with those

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't notice I needed this fellow. I didn't manage to make it work with ```ObjectCreate``` rather with ```ObjectCreated```, it now fails with ```Error: error putting S3 Bucket Notification Configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations```, but I had to ad permission to s3 to call the function.